# Javascript object property not multiline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am using a object in Javascript to store recipes and cannot get the "process" property to show as multiline. This has to be easy but not working. I am rendering the data as a

tag in react.js.

```
let recipes = [


            {
                id:1,
                dish: "Chicken and Rice",
                ingredients: "Left over chicken",
                process: "1)Chop up chicken in bite sized chunks\n 2)Heat 1 Tablespoon olive oil in your favorite pan\n3) Dice any veggies in your pantry and add these and chicken to pan and heat through.\n optional: Mix with fresh rice or quinoa to make more filling."
            },
            {
                id:2,
                dish: "Beef and Rice",
                ingredients: "Left over beef",
                process: "1)Chop up chicken in bite sized chunks <br> 2)Heat 1 Tablespoon olive oil in your favorite pan 3) Dice any veggies in your pantry and add these and chicken to pan and heat through optional: Mix with fresh rice or quinoa to make more filling."
            },



            {
                id:3,
                dish: "Rice and Rice",
                ingredients: "Left over beef",


            }


]
```

export default recipes;

Comment: You have to use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) to render HTML from a string in react.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the string on `\n` and map each line to an element.

```
render: function() {
    let process = "1)Chop up chicken in bite sized chunks\n 2)Heat 1 Tablespoon olive oil in your favorite pan\n3) Dice any veggies in your pantry and add these and chicken to pan and heat through.\n optional: Mix with fresh rice or quinoa to make more filling.";
    let lines = process.split("\n");
    let mappedLines = lines.map((line)=>{
        return <p>{line}</p>
    });

    return <div>{mappedLines}</div>;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82459/